# Does adding libraries/APIs increase apk size?

Tags: android, facebook, api, apk, android-support-library

Does adding Apis and Libraries such as the Facebook Api, Twitter Api etc increase apk size?
If they do, what are some measures I can take to minimize the size of my apk?

(I heard it is possible to filter the exported regions so that only ones you need are exported. I know this applies to support libraries but I am not sure if it applies to apks)

I would be very grateful for any help or tips!

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate more on this, you can use this code in your app level build.gradle file:

> Minimize resources configurations
>
> Android development often relies on the use of external libraries such
>   as Android Support Library, Google Play Services, Facebook SDK, etc.
>   All of theses libraries comes with resources that are not necessary
>   useful to your application. For instance, Google Play Services comes
>   with translations for languages your own application don’t even
>   support. It also bundles mdpi resources I don’t want to support in my
>   application.
>
> Starting Android Gradle Plugin 0.7, you can pass information about the
>   configurations your application deals with to the build system. This
>   is done thanks to the resConfig and resConfigs flavor and default
>   config option. The DSL below prevents aapt from packaging resources
>   that don’t match the app managed resources configurations:
>   [See full article here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/)

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
   resConfigs "en"
   resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi"
}
```

and also use these properties of proguard as per @shkschneider's comment in other answer:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

In my case I was able to shrink my 3.8 MB app to 1.8 MB by using just these two things. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

use *Proguard* and make it shrink and remove unused classes from your package..

Comment: The new Gradle directives `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` are indeed doing the job to correct that.